# Иконки awesome не отображаются на сайте wordpress

Tags: wordpress

```
[feature icon="tablet" title="" color="1"]Покупая у нас, Вы экономите на услугах посредника[/feature] [feature icon="gift" title="" color="2"]Доставка покупок в консолидированной посылке с большим весом стоит дешевле[/feature] [feature icon="gift" title="" color="3"]100% безналоговый штат - экономьте от 10% до 20% на каждой покупке[/feature] [feature icon="tablet" title="" color="4"]Чтобы быть «впереди планеты всей» и делать свой собственный выбор[/feature] [feature icon="tablet" title="" color="5"]Потому что можно совершать выгодные покупки в США, находясь у себя дома.[/feature] [feature icon="tablet" title="" color="6"]Потому что можно совершать выгодные покупки в США, находясь у себя дома.[/feature] [feature icon="bell" title="" color="7"]Покупая товары напрямую в США, Вы не переплачиваете за искусственные наценки магазинов[/feature] [feature icon="signal" title="" color="8"]Покупая товары в США, вы 100% получите оригиналы и реально качественные вещи, а не дешевый китайский ширпотреб.[/feature] [feature icon="tablet" title="" color="9"]У вас есть возможность получить то, что еще не продается или никогда не появится на витринах нашей страны.[/feature]
```

Вот такой отображается

Comment: @akbar, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: @akbar, Напишите код, дайте ссылку на пример, чтобы посмотреть.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы

```
[feature icon="tablet" title="" color="1"]Покупая у нас, Вы экономите на услугах посредника[/feature]
```

Преобразовывалось в то, что вам надо, у вас должен быть какой-то плагин или функция, которая преобразовывает это в html  код.

И тогда надо разбираться с этой функцией (кодом)

Comment: Я нашел сам ответ на свой вопрос! Когда эта ошибка произошла, я работал в Денвере  а когда я сайт на реальный сервер загрузил, все иконки работали!